# Filling missing data in a table

Tags: missing-data, kdb, linear-interpolation

I have a problem with missing data.
So I have a returns table created this way:

```
returns:update logret:log ret from update ret:{0.0, 1_deltas x} mid by sym from spots;
```

and looking like this:

```
meta returns
c     | t f a
------| -----
date  | d    
time  | p    
sym   | s    
mid   | f    
ret   | f    
logret| f
```

and I pivot it this way:

```
rettbl:0!exec (raze `$raze ( string (distinct sym)),\:/:("_",/:string `mid`ret`logret))!(mid, ret, logret) by time:time from returns;
```

so that works on a small range of time, but when I extend it fails with a "type: Mismatched types"

I believe the problem is that I don't have the same observations for all sym in my `returns` table, as
`select count time by sym from returns`
gives me a different count by sym.

So my question is: how would you go about filling any missing `mid` for all times I have in my table `returns`?
To make it quick and dirty i was thinking about having a linear interpolation for missing points between two `time ...
Any hint, link, etc... would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I can't share the data, but this should allow to reproduce the issue:

```
mid1: 1.2 + ({rand 1.0} each til 10) %100
mid2: 0.8 + ({rand 1.0} each til 10) %100
mid3: 104 + ({rand 1.0} each til 10) %100
sym1:{`$"EUR/USD"} each til 10
sym2:{`$"GBP/USD"} each til 10
sym3:{`$"USD/JPY"} each til 10
time1:2020.07.01D00:00:00.000000000 + 1D00:00:00 * til 10
/time2:2020.07.01D00:00:00.000000000 + 1D00:00:00 * til 10
time2:(2020.07.01D00:00:00.000000000 + 1D00:00:00 * til 3) , (2020.07.06D00:00:00.000000000 + 1D00:00:00 * til 3) , (2020.07.10D00:00:00.000000000 + 1D00:00:00 * til 4)
time3:2020.07.01D00:00:00.000000000 + 1D00:00:00 * til 10

spots:([] sym:sym1,sym2,sym3; time:time1,time2,time3; mid:mid1,mid2,mid3)
spots:update date:"d"$time from spots
returns:update logret:log ret from update ret:{0.0, 1_deltas x} mid by sym from spots;
rettbl:0!exec (raze `$raze ( string (distinct sym)),\:/:("_",/:string `mid`ret`logret))!(mid, ret, logret) by time:time from returns;
```

do note the time2 definition.
as per the desired output, if you replace the time2 definition with the one I commented out you will see.
as per the solution, I suspect that adding to the table returns the missing time, so that the list of time is the same for all sym are identical will solve the issue, ie value `select time by sym from returns` should be identical, and a quick a dirty work around would be to add missing mid with a linear interpolation of the surrounding mid.

Comment: could you provide a sample returns table?

Comment: also an expected output in order to understand what you want

Comment: Hi Mat. I did my best to create a table to reproduce the issue. I hope I'm clear about the cause of the problem (the time by sym are not the same) and about what im trying to achieve to solve it: the filling of the returns tables so that all time of the returns table are present for all sym, and the missing mid would be interpolated linearly. I believe the pivot wil work in these conditions.

Answer (score 3):

The `P#` is pretty crucial here in order to produce the pivot properly. This will place nulls where time is missing for a sym col. https://code.kx.com/q/kb/pivoting-tables/

```
{

    P:exec (raze `$raze ( string (distinct sym)),\:/:("_",/:string `mid`ret`logret)) from returns;
    exec P#(raze `$raze ( string (distinct sym)),\:/:("_",/:string `mid`ret`logret))!(mid, ret, logret) by time:time from returns

    }[]

Output:
time                         | EUR/USD_mid GBP/USD_mid USD/JPY_mid EUR/USD_re..
-----------------------------| ----------------------------------------------..
2020.07.01D00:00:00.000000000| 1.203915    0.8078337   104.0062    0         ..
2020.07.02D00:00:00.000000000| 1.200812    0.8040996   104.0093    -0.0031030..
2020.07.03D00:00:00.000000000| 1.209368    0.8061088   104.0027    0.00855514..
2020.07.04D00:00:00.000000000| 1.202782                104.0006    -0.0065853..
2020.07.05D00:00:00.000000000| 1.202392                104.0026    -0.0003897..
2020.07.06D00:00:00.000000000| 1.201508    0.8049765   104.0023    -0.0008842..
2020.07.07D00:00:00.000000000| 1.201567    0.8040875   104.0009    5.91839e-0..
2020.07.08D00:00:00.000000000| 1.209785    0.8044973   104.001     0.00821768..
2020.07.09D00:00:00.000000000| 1.207043                104.0087    -0.0027416..
2020.07.10D00:00:00.000000000| 1.209442    0.8001392   104.0073    0.00239835..
2020.07.11D00:00:00.000000000|             0.8071488                         ..
2020.07.12D00:00:00.000000000|             0.8019465                         ..
```

You are getting a type error because the code is creating a dictionary when time is not present for all syms.

```
q)0!exec (raze `$raze ( string (distinct sym)),\:/:("_",/:string `mid`ret`logret))!(mid, ret, logret) by time:time from returns
'type
  [0]  0!exec (raze `$raze ( string (distinct sym)),\:/:("_",/:string `mid`ret`logret))!(mid, ret, logret) by time:time from returns
        ^
q)exec (raze `$raze ( string (distinct sym)),\:/:("_",/:string `mid`ret`logret))!(mid, ret, logret) by time:time from returns
time                         |                                               ..
-----------------------------| ----------------------------------------------..
2020.07.01D00:00:00.000000000| `EUR/USD_mid`GBP/USD_mid`USD/JPY_mid`EUR/USD_r..
2020.07.02D00:00:00.000000000| `EUR/USD_mid`GBP/USD_mid`USD/JPY_mid`EUR/USD_r..
2020.07.03D00:00:00.000000000| `EUR/USD_mid`GBP/USD_mid`USD/JPY_mid`EUR/USD_r..
2020.07.04D00:00:00.000000000| `EUR/USD_mid`USD/JPY_mid`EUR/USD_ret`USD/JPY_r..
2020.07.05D00:00:00.000000000| `EUR/USD_mid`USD/JPY_mid`EUR/USD_ret`USD/JPY_r..
```

Edit: To remove nulls you could use `fills` to fill forward non-null values. You also may want to use `.Q.id` to sanitize the table first. Columns such as `EUR/USD_mid` are tricky to work with due to the confusion with `over /`.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qid-sanitize

```
q)fills x
time                         | EURUSD_mid GBPUSD_mid USDJPY_mid EURUSD_ret   ..
-----------------------------| ----------------------------------------------..
2020.07.01D00:00:00.000000000| 1.203928   0.8049318  104.0047   0            ..
2020.07.02D00:00:00.000000000| 1.205171   0.8057852  104.0063   0.001243387  ..
2020.07.03D00:00:00.000000000| 1.20516    0.8008389  104.0097   -1.11147e-005..
2020.07.04D00:00:00.000000000| 1.204067   0.8008389  104.0023   -0.001093155 ..
2020.07.05D00:00:00.000000000| 1.201781   0.8008389  104.0095   -0.002285803 ..
```

This will remove most nulls except for any that exist in the first row. I don't have any experience writing something such as linear interpolation in kdb and I don't think it will replace nulls as well as fills. For example, the example data set has 3 nulls at the end in the EURUSD_mid column so can't be interpolated for those 3 entries.

Comment: Thank you Mat. got it for the P# . but the thing is, it's not really solving my problem which is to fill the missing mid. so after you pivot, on your output, the 11th and 12th for EUR/USD_mid are null, and the 4th and 5th for GBP/USD_mid are also null. And what I would like to do is to fill all these 0Nf with linearly interpolated values. for ex 4th GBP/USD_mid would be equal to 0.8061088 + (0.804977-0.806109)/3 = 0.805731, and 11th of jul of EUR/USD_mid would be  1.206442 + (1.209442 - 1.207043). maybe it s too generic a question, but any pointer would be useful. Thanks in any case for the P#

Comment: ok i will check out fills and .Q.id. thanks again!